# Amazon RDS pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I want to understand how amazon RDS pricing works. I have already sent an email for amazon sales team, but I didn't get any response.

My specs are:

- 1 Instance of db.t2.micro ($0.017 per hour)
- Region us-east-1
- Usage 744 hours per month (31 days x 24 hours)
- Availability Standard Single A-Z
- Storage General Purpose SSD 5GB
- Inter-Region Data Transfer Out ???
- Data Transfer Out ???
- Data Transfer In ???
- Intra-Region Data Transfer ???

My scenario is one Heroku application communicating with Amazon RDS.

My questions are:

- Inter-Region Data Transfer Out: I won't have traffic here as heroku runs in the same region as Amazon RDS which is us-east-1, correct ?
- Data Transfer Out: is the data that comes out from Amazon RDS and goes to the internet (so here I won't have any traffic, because only my Heroku App will access my database). But I can see here that if I connect in my database through MySQL Workbench I will have some traffic in this item, correct ?
- Data Transfer In: is the data that comes from the Internet and goes to Amazon RDS (so here I won't have any traffic, because only my Heroku App will access my database). But I can see here that if I connect in my database through MySQL Workbench I will have some traffic in this item, correct ?
- Intra-Region Data Transfer: is the data sent/received between Heroku App and Amazon RDS, as they are in the same region which is us-east-1, correct ?
- Storage General Purpose SSD: I will be billed only for the data that I save in my database per month, correct ? For example, if I save 5GB per month in my database I will be billed in $0.575 ($0.115 x 5) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this community is going to suggest you remove your question here and re-post it at [Super User](http://superuser.com).  When you do that, please mention whether you are using VPC or EC2-Classic.  (New accounts only support VPC).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a question appropriate for StackOverflow, but...

There are no guarantees about traffic costs between Heroku and AWS within the same region. You'd have to experiment to be sure, or ask the Heroku folks (not the AWS folks).

If Heroku and RDS are in the same region, there shouldn't be any Data Transfer charges. However, it will incur the 1c/GB charge for **Using a public or Elastic IPv4 address**. Basically, this means traffic is exiting the VPC but not hitting the public Internet.

The **disk storage** for your Amazon RDS database is based on the *provisioned* size of storage. So, if you create a 5GB storage volume, you will be charged each month of 5GB regardless of how much it is used. There might be other charges based upon your chosen volume type (eg Provisioned IOPS has a charge based upon the speed, Magnetic has a charge based upon the IOs).

Also, the `db.t2.micro` database you have chosen has limits around CPU. It has burstable capacity but if it runs out of burst credits, it will only have limited CPU. See: [T2 instances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html)